# How to monitor a CakePHP application

Tags: cakephp, monitoring

I would like to get a better insight into my CakePHP application. Ideally, the report would be similar to those generated by New Relic RPM - http://www.newrelic.com/. Are there any plugins or services that can deliver these sorts of reports for CakePHP applications? I am looking for a **monitoring application** - not just a *debugging solution*.

Comment: Just found a module that does what I am looking for for Zend - http://www.zend.com/en/products/platform/product-comparison/php-intelligence

I really hope there is something like this for CakePHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Munin: http://munin.projects.linpro.no/

It's a monitoring application. You can write your own plugins!

Comment: I am looking for a solution that has already been integrated into CakePHP. Is there a CakePHP plugin available that utilizes Munin?

Comment: Just looking back on this question and I just wanted to give a status update. I went in a similar direction; however, instead of using Munin, we have gone with Nagios - http://www.nagios.org/. I still wish someone would write a plug-in for CakePHP that would make this more plug-n-play.

Answer (score 3):

Have a go with the DebugBar it might do what you need.

http://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

Comment: The other thing that I know of which tracks execution time is CacheGrind. http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/

Comment: I see this uses Xdebug... I wish there was something with a more rich interface like New Relic.